# Cannot see 'Send Email' button in Activity History in a Lightning

Tags: email, salesforce1-app, send-email

In my custom object I have added Activity History as a related list and I see "Log a  call" and "View all" button but I don't see the button "Send email".

Here is what I have check to make sure all the configuration is there.

In Lightning Experience: Click on the gear icon at the top right > Setup > User Interface > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts > Global Layout > Drag the Email action from Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Actions on the palette and drop it on the layout. > Click Save.

I still don't see the "Send email"

Also, I check the following:

Go to Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability.

Change Access level picklist to "All email".

What else I'm missing ? any help

EDIT: adding screen shots:

EDIT layout:
[image]

Comment: Check if 'Send Email' setting under 'General User Permissions' on the profile is checked?

Comment: the `send email` is checked

Comment: can you edit and add screenshot to the question of missing button pls.

Comment: In lightning,  you would see under the Activity tab (log a call, Email, etc) on the related list. (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331369&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: I have gone through the link but still I don’t see the email button. But if I changed to classic mode then I can see the email button. So only in lightning the email button is not showing.

Comment: Check this link, I found a solution there. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331369&type=1